# Dirac delta and covariance

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, field-theory, dirac-delta-distributions, covariance

Is there a covariant form of the Dirac delta function? And how to build a covariant form of an identity that contains Dirac delta?
To be more precise, what I am looking for is Some distribution that becomes the delta function in Minkowski spacetime, but which we can use in general spacetimes consistently with the principle of general covariance. Is there such a thing?

Comment: What do you mean by "covariant" here?

Comment: Some distribution that becomes the delta function in Minkowski spacetime,  but which we can use in general spacetimes consistently with the principle of general covariance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generalising a Dirac Delta function formula in General Relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/348039/)

Comment: That's very helpful! Thank you my friend ^_^
@G. Smith